# Entity framework Explicit Loading multi-level

Tags: entity-framework, explicit

I tried load multi-level with explicit loading but an error occurred:

> "The property path 'Channel.Posts' cannot be used for navigation properties. Property paths can only be used to access primitive or complex properties."

This is my code:

```
var listSubs;

using (var db = new GamePortalContext())
{
    listSubs = db.Subscribers.Include("Channel").Where(o => o.User.Username == username.ToLower() &&  o.Channel.IsActive && o.Channel.IsPublic && o.Channel.Posts.Count(p => p.PublishTime <= DateTime.Now && p.IsActive && p.IsHot) > 0);
    if (listSubs.Any())
    {
        listSubs = listSubs.OrderByDescending(o => o.Channel.ChannelTrack.LastPublishTime);
        listSubs = (num == int.MinValue) ? listSubs : listSubs.Take(num);
        foreach (var item in listSubs)
        {
            db.Entry(item).Collection(o => o.Channel.Posts).Query().Where(i => i.IsHot && i.IsActive && i.PublishTime <= DateTime.Now).Take(numpost).Load();
        }

        return listSubs.ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here is my post and channel entity

> public partial class Post
>
> {
>
> ```
>   public Post()
>
>   {
>
>        this.ReadPostLaters = new HashSet<ReadPostLater>();
>
>    }
>     public string PostId { get; set; }
>     public string Name { get; set; }
>     public string Alias { get; set; }
>     public string Description { get; set; }
>     public bool IsActive { get; set; }
>     public bool IsHot { get; set; }
>     public System.DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
>     public System.DateTime PublishTime { get; set; }
>     public int Views { get; set; }
>     public bool IsSticked { get; set; }
>     public int UpdatedTime { get; set; }
>     public bool IsSaved { get; set; }
>     public Nullable<int> ChannelId { get; set; }
>     public long UserId { get; set; }
>     public int PostType { get; set; }
>     public string UrlAvatar { get; set; }
>     public virtual Article Article { get; set; }
>     public virtual Channel Channel { get; set; }
>     public virtual Event Event { get; set; }
>     public virtual User User { get; set; }
>     public virtual ICollection<ReadPostLater> ReadPostLaters { get; set; }
>     public virtual Video Video { get; set; }
> }
> ```
>
> public partial class Channel
>
> {
>
> ```
>    public Channel()
>    {
>         this.Ads = new HashSet<Ad>();
>         this.ChannelAdmins = new HashSet<ChannelAdmin>();
>         this.ChannelPlayers = new HashSet<ChannelPlayer>();
>         this.Notifications = new HashSet<Notification>();
>         this.Posts = new HashSet<Post>();
>         this.Subscribers = new HashSet<Subscriber>();
>     }
>     public int ChannelId { get; set; }
>     public string Name { get; set; }
>     public string Username { get; set; }
>     public int Voters { get; set; }
>     public int Subs { get; set; }
>     public float SiteScore { get; set; }
>     public float UserScore { get; set; }
>     public string HomeUrl { get; set; }
>     public string FanpageUrl { get; set; }
>     public string Publisher { get; set; }
>     public int Players { get; set; }
>     public Nullable<System.DateTime> PublishDate { get; set; }
>     public string Status { get; set; }
>     public bool IsActive { get; set; }
>     public bool IsHot { get; set; }
>     public bool IsPublic { get; set; }
>     public bool IsNew { get; set; }
>     public bool IsChanneling { get; set; }
>     public int CategoryId { get; set; }
>     public string UrlAvatar { get; set; }
>     public string UrlCover { get; set; }
>     public virtual ICollection<Ad> Ads { get; set; }
>     public virtual CategoryChannel CategoryChannel { get; set; }
>     public virtual ICollection<ChannelAdmin> ChannelAdmins { get; set; }
>     public virtual ICollection<ChannelPlayer> ChannelPlayers { get; set; }
>     public virtual ChannelTrack ChannelTrack { get; set; }
>     public virtual ICollection<Notification> Notifications { get; set; }
>     public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
>     public virtual ICollection<Subscriber> Subscribers { get; set; }
> }
> ```

Comment: Post your `Channel` class please, or whatever type `Channel` is.

Comment: a Channel include posts, Channel is an Entity generate from my DB, and Relate with Posts Entity: one-many.

Comment: You should also post your `Post` entity.

Comment: i have just posted Channel and Post entity in my question

Answer (score 7):

change

```
db.Entry(item).Collection(o => o.Channel.Posts).Query().Where(i => i.IsHot && i.IsActive && i.PublishTime <= DateTime.Now).Take(numpost).Load();
```

to

```
db.Entry(item.Channel).Collection(o => o.Posts).Query().Where(i => i.IsHot && i.IsActive && i.PublishTime <= DateTime.Now).Take(numpost).Load();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this line:

```
listSubs = db.Subscribers.Include("Channel").Where(o => o.User.Username == username.ToLower() &&  o.Channel.IsActive && o.Channel.IsPublic && o.Channel.Posts.Count(p => p.PublishTime <= DateTime.Now && p.IsActive && p.IsHot) > 0);
```

To also call `.Include("Channel.Posts")`:

```
listSubs = db.Subscribers.Include("Channel").Include("Channel.Posts") .. etc;
```

Comment: I want to apply filter to posts.EagerLoading (your demo) can't not apply filter. what can i do?

Comment: @Steve thanks for the .Include technique... I was wondering how I could explicit load data from linked cascading tables in my database. This approach is really simple and fast and triggers only one sql request!!